# Calculating wire size for solar array

Tags: electrical, wiring, solar-panels, solar

How can I calculate wire size to go from a solar array (of 36 panels, 365W & 42V each) to a shed with an inverter 50 ft away?

Comment: What is the series/parallel arrangement?  Are all panels paralleled (42V to the inverter)?  Or are they series/parallel strings?

Comment: Not setup yet. I am buying a kit from shopsolarkits.com. Sounds like talking to a solar specialist might be a must ;)

Comment: Yes, solar and off-grid power are fairly demanding of technical skills.

Answer (score 0):

I am no electrician, but from what I am reading - wattage and voltage accumulate with every new panel, while amperage stays the same. Hence my AMP would be 365/42 = 8.7 A. Using [this calculator](https://www.renogy.com/calculators#tab_solar-cable) my gauge should be 16 AWG (1,512V, 9A, 50Ft, 1% loss). This seems too thin.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139725/discussion-on-answer-by-i-calculating-wire-size-for-solar-array).

Comment: Conceptually, could be add A, add V or a mix. But can't be strictly add V in your case because 36 * 42 = 1,512V - that's way beyond normal residential wiring.

Comment: Depending how you connect the panels you can increase the current for the same voltage or increase the voltage for the same current - approximately... HOWEVER, when I siz3ed my cables I looked at the voltage and current maxima and then chose a cable to exceed the current by 20%, and also make sure of the voltage ie insulation - I am well aware of voltage drop ie losses. Even the electrician who came to commission our system said he was impressed.